# Proof that change in a function can take a certain form $Δf(x)=g(x)⋅h+ε(h)h$ where h is the change in x and $Δf(x)$ is f(x+h)-f(x)?

Tags: calculus

I was reading this page here: [What are differentials?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69790/what-are-differentials), and I noticed that the answer to the question based on re-writing the change of a function, f(x+h)-f(x). The change in f(x) was denoted as Δf(x,h) where h is the change in the input, x. I am confused on how the alternate form Δf(x,h)=k(x)⋅h+ε(h)h was derived, and if this form fits for all functions of x, such as exponential or trigonometric functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $x$ you can define $\epsilon (h)=\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)-g (x)h} h$.  However you cannot make $\epsilon (h)$ independent of $x$ in general. For example, if $f(x)=e^{x}$ then  $\epsilon (h)$ depends on $x$

Comment: There is only one way of finding $\epsilon (h)$ for any function. Define it the way I have done in  my answer.