# The Substitution rule

Tags: calculus, integration

I am attempting to learn about the substitution rule and I can't make sense of what Stewart is trying to say. "To find this integral we use the problem solving strategy of introducing something extra. Here the something extra is a new variable, we change from the variable x to a new variable u. Suppose that we let u be the quantity under the root sing 1, $u=1+x^2$ Then the differential of u is du=2xdx. Notice that if the dx in the notation for an integral were to be interpreted as a differnetial then the differential 2xdx would occur in 1 and so formally without justifying our calculation we could write" The rest doesn't really matter, I just don't understand what is going on at all.

The differential of u is $.5(1+x^2)(2x)$ not what he has.

1: $\int 2x \sqrt{1+x^2}$

Comment: How do you get that the differential of $u$ is $.5(1+x^2)2x$? If $u=1+x^2$, then $du = d(1+x^2) = d(1)+d(x^2) = 0 + 2x\,dx$, exactly what Stewart says.

Comment: What does du=2xdx mean? The differnetial of du with respect to u is equal to 2x differential of dx with respect to x?

Comment: It means that if $u=1+x^2$, then "a small change in $u$" (the differential) will necessarily be the same size as a "small change in $x$" (the differential in $x$) times twice the value of $x$ you are in. But I repeat my question: why is it that you think that "the differential of $u$ is $0.5(1+x^2)(2x)$." In your mind, what does *that* mean and *why* is that what the differential of $u$ "is"?

Comment: I was reading it too quickly and took the differential of the square root of u not u. I really do not know what you are talking about small changes, is this something to do with reimann sums?

Comment: Do you remember what a differential is? If you don't know what a differential is, then of course you can't make sense of any explanation for why they are what they are. I don't know if [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23902/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-a-differential-and-a-derivative/23914#23914) will help.

Comment: Off the top of my head a differential is the small difference in a function.

Comment: I have read that already and I can make sense of it a little bit but I always forget.

Comment: @Jordan Might I suggest you take a look at The Calculus Lifesaver videos - http://press.princeton.edu/video/banner/ - specifically video 12 addresses u-substitution.

Answer (score 2):

The $u$ he is referring to is $1+x^2$, not $\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

I prefer the following explanation for ``$u$-substitution'' (which avoids any $u$'s at all):

The basic method for finding an antiderivative is to recall a corresponding derivative rule:
if you know a basic derivative rule, then you know a basic antiderivative rule.

Here, we regard a function arising from an application of the chain rule as a ``basic derivative''.
Given one of these, it is easy to find its antiderivative so long as you recognize that it is a derivative resulting from using the chain rule.

What expressions result from applying the chain rule? Well, they have the form of a product of a *composition* of functions with the derivative of the inner function of the composition.

For example, for the integral
$$
\int 2x\cos(x^2)\,dx, 
$$

the required antiderivative is $\sin x^2+C$.  Why? Well, you just need to see it; which you would if you've mastered differentiation and the use of the chain rule (my apologies if this sounds condencending, I didn't mean for it to).

For the integral you give above $\int 2x\sqrt{1+x^2}\,dx$,  you should recognize that
${- 2\over3}(1+x^2)^{3/2}+C$ would work.

With $u$ substitution you're thinking "the integral
$$\int2x\sqrt{1+x^2}\,dx$$ 
is the same as the integral $$\int \sqrt u \,du$$ 
as long as $u$ is replaced by $1+x^2$ after evaluating the latter integral"

This $u$-substitution business is just a way of keeping track of things (which you'll eventually see after practicing with the method), especially when the integrand   is the product of a  composition  of functions with a function that is ''almost'' the derivative of the inner function of the composition.

I hope this helps. I could elaborate on the last paragraph if you think that would help further.

Comment: I don't understand the $2xcos(x^2)$ example, I don't know how to do products for antiderivatives so I wouldn't know how to do it but if I break it down (which I know I can't do) it would be $2, sin, 1/3x^3$

Comment: You want an $\it antiderivative$ of $2x\cos (x^2)$; that is, a function whose derivative is  $2x\cos (x^2)$. The antiderivative is $\sin x^2$ since ${d\over dx}\sin x^2=\cos( x^2)\cdot (x^2)'=2x\cos(x^2)$

Comment: I don't understand how you know that, the derivative of $sinx^2$ is  not something I would have to use something like the chain rule on?

Comment: $\sin (x^2)$ is a composition of functions ($sin x$ and $x^2$). You need the chain rule to differentiate it. Though I really don't like doing things this way: ''the derivative of the function "$\sin$ of something" is $\cos$ of the something times the derivative of the something.  You do recognize that $\sin x^2$ is a composition ($\sin {\rm\ of\ } x^2$)?

Comment: So wouldnt it be like $(sinx)^2$ and the antiderivative would be $1/3 cosx^3$ ?

Comment: no, $\sin(x^2)$ and $(\sin x)^2$ are different (in the former, you square $x$ first). Also, the antiderivative of $(\sin x)^2$ is not $(1/3)(\sin x)^3$; but the antiderivative of $(\sin x)^2\cdot \cos x$ $\it is$  $(1/3)(\sin x)^3$.

Comment: So it is like sinu and u is $x^2$ so I have $cosx^2(2x)$? So the antiderivative would be (-cosx^2)(1/3x^3)$ ?

Comment: @Jordan: (i) You are composing "first $\sin x$, *then* the square". When composing functions, the order matters; here, you do "first the square, *then* the sine". (ii) The **derivative** of $\sin(x^2)$ is $2x\cos (x^2)$. The **derivative** of $(\sin x)^2$ is $2(\sin x)(\cos x)$. The antiderivative of $(\sin x)^2$ is *not* just $\frac{1}{3}(\cos x)^3$, because the derivative of the latter is *not* $(\sin x)^2$; it's $(\cos x)^2(-\sin x)$ by the Chain Rule.

Comment: Yes, If I understand you correctly; except you start with $2x\cos x^2$ and replace with $\sin u$ (in the integral, the dx becomes du also). It seems we can't ''chat'' here, so this will be my last comment.

Comment: I don't understand this at all, I think I just have to wait until someone can explain it to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'll probably get stoned to death for such a clumsy answer, but here's how I do substitution problems:

Basically what you need to do is to get a just a single variable under the square root - that's the $u$ you are substituting. What you want to do is to find a substitution of a form that after derivation produces a differential that will "nullify" the $2x$ from $2x\sqrt{1 + x^2}$

So you go like this:

$$
\begin{align*}
u =& 1 + x^2\\
du =& 2x \ dx\\
dx =&\frac{du}{2x}
\end{align*}
$$

So now when you subsitute:

$$
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{2x}{2x}\sqrt{u}\ du\\
\int 1\sqrt{u}\ du\\
\int \sqrt{u}\ du
\end{align*}
$$

So the integral is:
$$
\int \sqrt{u}\ du= \frac{2}{3}u^{\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{2}{3}(1+x^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}
$$