# Question about the differential in Calculus

Tags: calculus

Question about the differential in Calculus.
Assume a function  y = f(x) , differentiable everywhere.  Now  we have for some   Δx

Δy = f(x + Δx) -  f(x)

The differential  of x,  is defined as “dx”, can be any real number, and  dx = Δx

The differential  of y, is defined by “dy” and
dy = f’(x) dx

Clearly,

Δy  ≈  dy, depending on the magnitude of Δx.

In calculus an expression like “dx” usually denotes something infinitesimally small.
Why is it necessary to have dy and dx used as real numbers of some magnitude?   In specifying and solving calculus problems are not the usual symbols sufficient?
Is it just a matter of notational convenience?

Comment: What are "the usual symbols"?

Comment: $dx,dy$ are extremely usual

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23902/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-a-differential-and-a-derivative/23914#23914) answer your question?

Comment: Many thanks Monsieur Magidin for the link.  Obviously the "dx" notation is useful practically in applying such results as the chain  and inverse derivative rules.   What is sometimes confusing is going from  Δy  ≈ f'(x) Δx   (which makes sense) to  dy = f'(x) dx which is not some deep result, but rather an expression defining both dy  and dx.  such that dx = Δx.  Your historical review certainly explains the origin of this state of affairs, many thanks for making it available.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is just to have an intuition that the derivative is the range of the tangent line. It also helps to understand "instantaneous velocity" when studying physics. The average velocity between time $t$ and time $t+\Delta t$ is given by

$$\frac{f(t+\Delta t)-f(t)}{\Delta t},$$

where $f$ is the position. So, it's quite intuitive that it gets  closer and closer than the velocity at time $t$ as you decrease $\Delta t$.