# confusion between differential, derivative and gradient

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule, gradient-descent, frechet-derivative

Consider a function space $\mathcal{F}$ and functions $F : \mathbb{R}^P \to \mathcal{F}$ and $C : \mathcal{F} \to \mathbb{R}$. Now, the derivative of $C \circ F$ w.r.t. $\theta$ can be written down by means of the chain rule (using Fréchet derivatives/differentials):

$$\mathrm{d}(C \circ F)(\theta) = \mathrm{d}C(f_\theta) \circ \mathrm{d}F(\theta)$$

where $f_\theta = F(\theta)$.

Now, we want to optimise the parameters $\theta$ to minimise the function $C \circ F$. Using gradient descent for optimisation, the following relation should hold:

$$\mathrm{d}\theta_p(t)(1) = -\mathrm{d}(C \circ F)(\theta)(e_p),$$

with $\mathrm{d}\theta_p$ the partial derivative of $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^P$ w.r.t. the $p$-th component,
and thus change to the function $f_\theta$ is given by

$$\mathrm{d}f_\theta(t) = \mathrm{d}F(\theta_t) \circ \mathrm{d}\theta(t).$$

---

This piece of mathematics comes from a [paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2018/file/5a4be1fa34e62bb8a6ec6b91d2462f5a-Paper.pdf) that I roughly understand. Also the general idea behind the mathematics above is clear to me. However, there are some technicalities that cause some troubles for me:

1. Is there any difference between differentials and derivatives and if yes, is there a way to express the difference(s) and similarit(y)(ies)? In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23902/what-is-the-practical-difference-between-a-differential-and-a-derivative) it is stated that derivative and differential are different things. Also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function) states something in the same lines. However, the [Fréchet **derivative**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) seems to be a differential to my untrained eye and when looking at the page for [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative), derivative and differential are used interchangeably.
2. Is there a way to express $\mathrm{d}\theta(t)$ directly, given the expression for the partials $\mathrm{d}\theta_p(t)$? In an attempt to do it by myself, I had written something like
   $$\underbrace{\mathrm{d}\theta(t)}_{\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^P} = -\underbrace{\mathrm{d}(C \circ F) (\theta)}_{\mathbb{R}^P \to \mathbb{R}},$$
   which obviously can not work. I realised that I might need a gradient rather than a derivative (I somehow always thought that gradients and derivatives are synonyms), but when using [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Derivative) as a reference again, a gradient can only be defined for functions $f : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$. Although $C \circ F$ should have a gradient with this definition, it is unclear how it would be defined when applied to the chain rule. Again, I would be inclined to write something like
   $$\underbrace{\mathop{\nabla}(C \circ F)(\theta)}_{\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^P} = \underbrace{\mathop{\nabla}C(f_\theta)}_{\mathbb{R} \to \mathcal{F}} \circ \underbrace{\mathop{\nabla}F(\theta)}_{\mathcal{F} \to \mathbb{R}^P},$$
   but that probably makes no sense again mathematically.

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.