# Solving logarithmic derivative in implicit form

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I have the following function
$$
a\text{log}\left(X\right)+b\text{log}\left(y\right)=c\left[d\text{log}\left(X\right)+e\text{log}\left(y\right)\right]+\text{log}\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)
$$
I wish to compute the following derivative:
$$
\frac{\partial\log\left(\frac{X}{Y}\right)}{\partial\log\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)}
$$

I have tried numerous techniques, but am not sure how to proceed.
I imagine the implicit function theorem is appropriate here, but I
am unable to write the LHS in terms of $\log\left(\frac{X}{Y}\right)$
given the presence of $a$ and $b$ coefficients. Any pointers on
this are much appreciated.

Comment: Use `\log` instead of `\text{log}` for a nicer display with better spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\delta$ as a symbol for differential to avoid confusion with constant $d$, we have

$$a\log\left(X\right)+b\log\left(Y\right)=c\left[d\log\left(X\right)+e\log\left(Y\right)\right]+\log\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)$$

$$a\delta\log\left(X\right)+b\delta\log\left(Y\right)=c\left[d\delta\log\left(X\right)+e\delta\log\left(Y\right)\right]+\delta\log\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)$$

$$(a-cd)\delta\log\left(X\right)+(b-ce)\delta\log\left(Y\right)=\delta\log\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)$$

$$(a-cd)\delta\log\left(\frac X Y\right)+(a+b-cd-ce)\delta\log\left(Y\right)=\delta\log\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)$$

$$(a-cd)\delta\log\left(\frac X Y\right)=\delta\log\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)-(a+b-cd-ce)\delta\log\left(Y\right)$$

$$\frac{\delta\log\left(\frac X Y\right)}{\delta\log\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)}=\frac{1-(a+b-cd-ce)\frac{\delta\log\left(Y\right)}{\delta\log\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)}}{a-cd}$$

with $a-cd \neq 0$ and for $a+b-cd-ce=0$

$$\frac{\delta\log\left(\frac X Y\right)}{\delta\log\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)}=\frac 1{a-cd}$$

Comment: I have always thought that differentials and derivates are different, in that we cannot think of the derivative as a fraction. Is this not what you have done here?

Comment: Yes, they are indeed different but by definition the ratio between differential is the derivative. You can find a detailed discussion here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/23902/505767