# What is $\int{\sqrt{dx}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How would I compute the integral $\int{\sqrt{dx}}$?

I would suppose it is recursive like this:

$\int{(dx)^2} = (x + C)dx$

Is this a well formed mathematical term? I can imagine it is because

$\iint{(dx)^2} = \frac{x^2}{2} + Cx + D$ and thus $\frac{d\iint{dx^2}}{dx} = x + C$ and then $\int{dx^2} = (x + C)dx$.

Comment: It is just $\sqrt x + C$

Comment: You can interpret '$d$' and '$\int$' as operators on functions. In that context $\int d(f(x))=f(x)$

Comment: $df(x) = f^\prime(x) dx$. So $\int df = \int f^\prime(x) dx = f+C$ and the result from the two earlier comments is correct.

Comment: I corrected the question. It was not really what I meant, I forgot some brackets

Comment: What is $C$ here? It can stand for *any* constant. This way $\int$ is sending functions to a *set of functions*. The function $x^2$ is one of them. Then $\int$ is *not* an operator on functions anymore and you have stepped out of context I mentioned.

Comment: In what context have you seen this notation ($\sqrt{dx}$)? I have never seen it before.

Comment: It was something that appeared to me because (dx)^2 is well formed also. Why should I not apply the sqrt-function to dx?

Comment: Your edit makes my comments irrelevant. Btw, just like @mrf I am not familiar with the updated notation.

Comment: If you just made it up yourself, it's up to you to tell others how it is supposed to be interpreted. Preferably with a useful interpretation.

Comment: It means what it states. You just substitute the definition of dx into $\sqrt(dx)$. I don't think that needs a definition.

Comment: What do you mean by "$dx$" then? Is it a differential 1-form? Something else? Do you intend the symbol $\sqrt{dx}$ to have meaning on its own? Or just coupled with an integral sign? [In other words: do you see where I'm heading? Of course it needs a definition if anyone is supposed to make sense out of it.]

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143222/what-does-dx-mean

Comment: @WorldSEnder, how about if I substitute the definition (from logic) of $\implies$ into $\sqrt\implies$.  Does that not need a definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\int{\sqrt{dx}}$ is an ambiguous symbolism, as already pointed out by several posters.

The tone of the question draw me to think that you are looking for something like "fractionnal calculus", i.e. antiderivative and derivative of non-integer degree. In this sense, it should be better to raise the question on this form :

How would I compute $\frac{d^\nu}{dx^\nu}f(x)$ ? where $\nu=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x)=1$ in your example.

For information, see:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalIntegral.html

Your particular case corresponds to the definition of "semi-integral", i.e. fractionnal integral of order 1/2 , as shown here :

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Semi-Integral.html

The result is :
$$\frac{d^{-1/2}}{dx^{-1/2}}(1)=2\sqrt{\frac{x}{\pi}}$$

A paper for general public is available here :

https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14686539/The-Fractional-Derivation-La-derivation-fractionnaire

Note that your writting :

$\iint{(dx)^2} = \frac{x^2}{2} + Cx + D$ and thus $\frac{d\iint{dx^2}}{dx} = x + C$ and then $\int{dx^2} = (x + C)dx$

is not correct for two reasons : 
First, $\frac{d\iint{dx^2}}{dx}$ is not equal to $\int{dx^2}$ but is equal to $\int{dx}$.
Second : The right term cannot be an infinitesimal such as $(x + C)dx$. The $dx$ is too much.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted although I wasn't able to phrase it.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: There was a mistake in my answer. The fourth link, confused with the third, is now corrected as : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14686539/The-Fractional-Derivation-La-derivation-fractionnaire