# Trigonometric substitution and $dx$

Tags: integration, substitution

Normally, when computing integrals, I tend to see a $dx$ as "a little bit of x", but really rather use it to denote what is a variable, and what is a constant.
Most of the answers on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143222/what-does-dx-mean) question support that notion.

Now I started looking into trigonometric substitutions, and in various sources a term $dx$ becomes an important part of the expression after substitution.
For example, [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution) starts off with the following integral:
$$\int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}}$$

and then defines:
$$ x = a(\sin(\theta)),\,dx =a(\cos(\theta))\,d\theta$$

where clearly, $dx$ becomes the derivative of the substitution for $x$ times $d\theta$.

Is this the same $dx$ as in other integrals? Why does it become such a key-role in these substitutions, when in other integrals it is viewed as just a "notational thing" to denote the variable? I would have expected that a change of variables would have just turned a $dx$ into a $d\theta$. Why does it not work that way?

Comment: There is a little handwaving involved.  $x$ is defined by the given equation.  $\frac {dx}{d\theta}$ is derived leading to a relationship between $dx$ and $d\theta$.  The differential is more than just notational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want to understand this, perhaps the only way is to go under the hood and see how a change of variables really works. A COV is not the fact that:
$$\int{U(x) dx } \,=\, \int{U(t) dt } \,=\, \int{U(i) di }.$$

This is merely notation; it is picking a letter.

Let's work with $f(x) \,=\, (4-x^2)^{-1/2}$ defined on $(-2,2)$. Because this function is continuous, it is the derivative of something. So we can talk about $F(x)$ defined on $(-2,2)$ with derivative $f(x)$.

Now let's look at our third function, $x(\theta) \,=\,2\sin \theta.$ We must note a few facts related to it.

- it is continuous on the interval $[-\pi / 2,\pi / 2]$.
- it is differentiable on the interval $(-\pi / 2,\pi / 2)$. (so we can have our fourth function $x'(\theta)$.)
- $x'(\theta)$ is strictly greater than zero inside its domain $(-\pi / 2,\pi / 2)$.
- we have a neat matchup of endpoints: $x(-\pi / 2) = -2, x(\pi / 2) = 2$.

All this indicates that $x(\theta)$ has an inverse function $\theta(x)$. Or in other words, the $x$'s are in one-to-one correspondence with the $\theta$'s. The upshot is, that although writing the following is the obvious choice

$$\int{f(x) dx } \,=\, F(x),$$

we are justified to rather take the point of view

$$\int{f(x) dx } \,=\, \Phi(\theta(x)).$$

(Here $\Phi$ performs the action: apply $F$ to the $x$ which corresponds to $\theta$.) Now perhaps you begin to see why a COV is more than just a notational thing. And, that this curious change in point of view is the key to making the substitution work. We need also the chain rule:

$$\frac{d}{d \theta} \Phi(\theta) \,\,=\,\, \frac{d}{d \theta} F(x(\theta)) \,\,=\,\, f(x(\theta))\,x'(\theta).$$

The third expression is a derivative in $(-\pi / 2,\pi / 2)$. Hence its integral is $\Phi(\theta)$. As your wiki page shows, $\Phi(\theta) = \theta.$

Lastly we say goodbye to $\theta$ by noting that $\theta(x) \,=\, \arcsin(x/2)$ and again that $\Phi(\theta(x)) = F(x)$.

I tried to do all this while avoiding any interpretation of 'dx'. Of course it is fine to think of $dx$ as the width of very skinny rectangles. But in the COV/substitution, you must think of the two intervals $-2 < x < 2$, $-\pi/2 < \theta < \pi/2$ and some differentiable bijection between them.

Comment: Interesting alternative procedure! Using the chain-rule in this context makes sense to me. So there seem to be two ways of seeing this.. one in which we directly replace $dx$, and one in which we concentrate on the transformation from $x$ into $\theta$, applying the chain-rule. Can you maybe share with me some insight on why both seem to be valid?

Comment: I do not think it is an alternative procedure. What I walked through is a proof that if $f$ has an indef. integral, and if the various conditions on $x(\theta)$ hold, then we can know that the integral which looks like the chain rule exists, and is just what we wanted. It is however a hidden procedure from many calculus students, who usually are just expected to 'learn how to do it'. As far as insight,  $x = a \sin \theta, \,\,\,\, \frac{dx}{d \theta} =a \cos \theta$. This last bit is more or less what you yourself wrote: $ dx =a(\cos(\theta))\,d\theta.$ Read about Leibniz's notation.

Comment: Also, if you are still curious, it might be time to pursue an understanding of Bernard's answer.

Answer (score 3):

That is because, if you interpret $\mathrm dx$ as a small variation $\Delta x$ of $x$, and if $x$ is a  function $f(\theta)$, where $f$  is a differentiable  function, $f'(\theta)\Delta \theta\:$ is the best linear approximation of $\Delta x$, in the very precise sense given by asymptotic analysis that
$$\Delta x=f'(\theta)\,\Delta \theta+o\bigl((\Delta\theta)^2\bigr).$$
Therefore one sets the differential element as
$$\mathrm dx=f'(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta.$$