What does the differential $dy$ (independent variable) really mean?
Let $f(x)$ be an arbitrary function, as shown in the figure below (Figure 1.1).

When $x$ increases by $h$, the change in $y$ is straightforward:
$$
   \Delta y = f(x+h) - f(x).
   $$

The average rate of change with respect to $h$ (where $h \neq 0$) is given by:
$$
   \frac{\Delta y}{h} = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}.
   $$


So far, this makes sense to me.
Now, I'm struggling with two things:
First:
I understand that Leibniz's notation, $\frac{dy}{dx}$, is just that — a notation. What it represents is the limit:
$$
   \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}.
   $$
But what about $dy$? Is $dy$ also "just" a notation, or does it have a different meaning? My interpretation is that:
$$
   dy = \left\{\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \right\} \cdot dx.
   $$
Is this correct?
Second:
Using Leibniz's notation, I could write:
$$
   dy = \frac{dy}{dx} \cdot dx.
   $$
However, this form contains two identical $dx$ symbols. One is in the denominator of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ (which is part of Leibniz's notation and doesn’t represent anything specific), and the other $dx$ represents the step in $x$. In this context, $dx = h$. This confuses me because both are written the same, but seem to mean different things. Can someone explain how to interpret these two $dx$ symbols correctly?


see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143222/what-does-dx-mean

$\Delta$y is the vertical distance between the y-coordinates of the two points on the function graph, while dy is the vertical distance between the y-coordinate of the first point and the y-coordinate the line tangent to the first point passes through after the same horizontal distance, as your graph shows.

This question has the most duplicates on MSE. Here is one: What does $dx$ mean?.

For your first question, the answer is NO. A limit does not, and cannot, represent an infinitesimal. (The concept of a limit is designed specifically to eliminate infinitesimals, leaving only definite values.) Regarding your second question, you are correct that $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ is not a typical fraction but rather an inseparable entity of its own. You are also correct that the standalone $\mathrm{d}x$ must be defined independently of Leibniz's notation, which can indeed be accomplished with full mathematical rigor but requires a certain level of mathematical maturity.

@SangchulLee thanks a lot fr you anser. Ok thanks for answering question 2. This is ok for me now. But regarding question 1. you wrote " A limit does not, and cannot, represent an infinitesimal". but I wrote "$dy = \left{\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \right} \cdot dx$" there is also this $dx$ as factor on the right hand side and the on the left hand side there is the limit $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ which means in Leibnitz notation $dy/dx$, so $dy = \left{\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \right} \cdot dx$ is not correct? thx and best regards

@MarcoMoldenhauer, Ah, I see that now. Somehow I failed to notice the factor $\mathrm{d}x$ in the right-hand side. That makes sense. :)
