# Is this a correct way to see differentials in calculus?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, definition

I'm trying to get a grasp on the differentials concept and I arrived to this conclusion, but I'm not sure it's correct since I haven't found exactly this way of defining them anywhere.

I'm pasting a picture of my notes because I'm not sure how to express this otherwise.

[image: Pic of my notes]

From my understanding, defining $dx$ and $dy$ this way gives me the following properties:

- Differentials are *limits*, not *numbers*, so they must be dealt with using [algebra of limits](https://sun.iwu.edu/~lstout/limitTheorems/node3.html)
- Differentials represent infinitesimal quantities

I want to check if these deductions are correct, misguided or maybe plain wrong.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my english Zev!.

Comment: Limits are numbers, if they exist. $\lim_{\text{your favorite symbol}\to0}\text{your favorite symbol}=0$, always.

Comment: Your definition of the derivative is wrong; you can't take the limit of the numerator and denominator separately, since this gives the undefined expression “0/0”.

Comment: i just checked [algebra of limits](http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/lHopital/limit_laws.html) again and you are right, it can only be done if the denominator's limit is not cero, so my intuition was plain wrong. thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any definitions of $dx$ and $dy$ there.  There **are** ways of defining differentials $dx$ and $dy$, but it's not as limits of $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$.  You might look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46530/can-i-ever-go-wrong-if-i-keep-thinking-of-derivatives-as-ratios)
 and its answers.

Comment: So the fact that a derivative can be defined as the quotients of limits of $ Δ x$ has nothing to do with the notation $dx/dy$ ?

Comment: It only has to do historically. "Differentials" are disgusting things to introduce in a first calculus course.

Comment: Is it bad to interpret them in this way until i gain a better understanding of mathematics where i can understand Differentials with more rigor?

would this lead me to errors in practical applications of calculus, or while interpreting calculus books?

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan Y... Es medio difícil de decir. Muchos profesores, especialmente en física van a usar argumentos con "diferenciales" para explicar conceptos, sin siquiera ellos saber que son realmente (como mucho te dirán "son números muy chiquitos!"). Es por esta razón que siempre odie que siquiera introduzcan esta notación para la derivada. Cuando estudies más matemática (si es que estas estudiando algo como licenciatura en matemática), en algún momento vas a ver formas diferenciales, que clarifica un poco más estos conceptos, pero no te apresures.

Comment: Y cada vez que hagan cosas como "multiplicar diferenciales", tómalo con pinzas (creo que la mejor interpretación que se le puede dar a $dy/dx$ en este punto es como un solo símbolo (no $dy$ dividido por $dx$, tal como $\log x$ no es $l\cdot o\cdot g \cdot x$ : )). Saludos.