# Question regarding why treating differential terms like numbers is wrong?,Example:Why is multiplying and dividing a differential is wrong

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curvature

Let's consider the formula for curvature

$κ$=$|\frac{dT}{dS}|$

This is the rate of change of  $Tangent$ $vector$ as we walk along the curve.

Now a more useful way to represent this is multiplying and dividing by $dt$ ;

$κ$=$|\frac{\frac{dT}{dt}}{\frac{ds}{dt}}|$.

This seems logical to me as we can further simplify the expression as

$κ$=$\frac{1}{|\vec{v}|}$$|\frac{dT}{dt}|$.

This is a useful expression.

But from the perspective of a Mathematician, ***why does he abhor the idea of multiplying and dividing a differential ,what is the correct mathematical way to approach this?***

Comment: Who says you can't write the formula for curvature in all three ways? You don't need to literally do algebra with $dt$ in order to perform manipulations that **look** like you did algebra with $dt.$

Comment: Some questions about single-variable calculus, but since we're doing total derivatives here they still have relevance: [When not to treat dy/dx as a fraction in single-variable calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1906241/139123), [When can we not treat differentials as fractions? And when is it perfectly OK?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1784671/139123), [How is it that treating Leibniz notation as a fraction is fundamentally incorrect but at the same time useful?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/726950/139123)

Comment: Different context, but likely or possible duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When not to treat dy/dx as a fraction in single-variable calculus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906241/when-not-to-treat-dy-dx-as-a-fraction-in-single-variable-calculus)

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that it seems you are dividing differentials but you can interpret it as a change of variables.

For example, suppose $\color{blue}{\dfrac{dt}{ds}=\alpha(x,t)}$ and $\color{green}{\dfrac{dx}{ds}=\beta(x,t)}\implies \dfrac{\frac{dx}{ds}}{\frac{dt}{ds}}"="\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{\beta(x,t)}{\alpha(x,t)}$... Why?
Since $x=x(t(s))$, we have
$$\color{green}{\dfrac{dx}{ds}}=\dfrac{d}{ds}x(t(s))=\underbrace{\dfrac{d}{dt}x(t(s))\cdot\color{blue}{\dfrac{d}{ds} t(s)}}_{\text{chain rule}}=\dfrac{d}{dt}x\cdot\color{blue}{\alpha(x,t)}\implies\color{green}{\beta(x,t)}=\dfrac{dx}{dt}\cdot\color{blue}{\alpha(x,t)}\\\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{\beta(x,t)}{\alpha(x,t)}.$$

So when you see calculations in which it seems that differentials are treated as fractions you should see if the variables are implicitly dependent.